# Let default action go first

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There are some elements in html that have default events attached to it. In my case, I'm working with `<input type="text" id="filter">`

I've applied a keypress event to the input, like so:

```
$('#filter').on('keypress', function(){
 console.log($(this).val()); 
});
```

Here are a list of examples on what I press and what the log gives me:

*PRESSED* ==> *RESULT IN LOG*

1. 'a' ==> ''
2. 'aa' ==> 'a'
3. 'aaa' ==> 'aa'

As you can see the default event gets called after my event finishes. Meaning that on the keypress, my function writes the current value of the input's value in the log before it actually gets updated.

I would like to get the value ***after the value has been updated*** to avoid concatenating the old value with the converted key to a character.

Is there a way force the default action to go first? If not it's not a big deal, I'll just go with my second method. Just curious if it was possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is updated on key up, so use the `keyup` event instead

```
$('#filter').on('keyup', function(){
    console.log($(this).val()); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem. I'll accept the answer when I can.